# Error calling method on NPObject, When trying to combine Xamarin.Android with Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, xamarin.android

I have added java bindings for Cordova in my Xamarin.Android project and the project now builds successfully. (Following [This blog post](http://szymonrozga.net/blog/2013/02/maximizing-code-reuse-using-xamarin-and-cordova/) ),
However I had to make some changes in cordova android source (nothing important, just adding some access modifires).

But when I run the project, onDeviceReady will never invoke and perior to that, I am getting this error :
 **Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:917**

My Phonegap version (running "phonegap version" is : 3.5.0-0.20.10)
And at top of my Cordova.js (inside www folder which I copied form a fresh phonegap project) is 3.4.0

Any suggestions?